# Postgres SQL Statments, getting the right data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know Postgres has a lot of functions, and I'm not the fittest in SQL anyways, but I need to know if its possible with Postgres to somehow get the data in a table with that statement-

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='public'
```

I'm getting my tables I created which I want.
eg.

| table_name |
| --- |
| myTable1 |
| myTable2 |
| myTable3 |

Each of the Tables has different data filled, but every table has a column version and I want to access it.

Joining the tables wouldn't work at least it didn't went out the way I wanted. What I want is this

| table_name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| myTable1 | 21 |
| mytABLE2 | 12 |

with

```
Select version from mytable1 order by version desc limit 1
```

I get the last version but I would like to combine this somehow
I mean I can join the 3 tables but that's not what I want
So my question is it possible to do it? Or do I have to work around.
Because I believe that getting the table names is on a higher layer

Comment: So i guess the formatting of tabels dont work anymore

Comment: You need a a blank line before the table to make the formatting work.

Answer (score 1):

In the end you need dynamic SQL for this. One way to do it, is to use a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) function, another way is to use `query_to_xml()` to run a dynamic query without the use of PL/pgSQL.

```
with data as (
   select query_to_xml(format('select version 
                               from %I.%I 
                               order by version desc limit 1', 
                       t.table_schema, t.table_name), 
                       true, true, '') as result
   from information_schema.tables t
   where t.table_schema = 'public'
)
select (xpath('/row/version/text()', result))[1]::text::int as version
from data;
```

The `format()` function is used to build a SELECT query the way you need it. The `query_to_xml()` will then return something like:

```xml
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <version>21</version>
</row>
```

The `xpath()` function is then used to extract the `21` from that XML. As it returns an array of matches, the `[1]` is used to extract the first match. This is then converted to an integer.

Note that if there is at least one table that does not contain a column named `version` this query will fail. You can work around that by extending the WHERE clause to:

```
where table_schema = 'public'
  and exists (select *
              from information_schema.columns c
              where c.table_schema = t.table_schema
                and c.table_name = t.table_name
                and c.column_name = 'version'
```